# i cant replace ' , ' to ' ' in string type to convert it to integer

Tags: python

I thought I can use this code to convert a string:

```
str = "3,443"
str.replace(",", "")
int_num = int(str)
```

But it doesn't work and raises a `ValueError`. How can I convert this string?

Comment: do not name your variables with reserved words like `str`. that shadows the builtin `str` function. also, strings are immutable. modifying them will return a _new_ string

Comment: Please, don't use `str` as a variable name. You will replace the default python str class. In any case, str.replace, doesn't change the variable value.

Comment: `str.replace` is one way to do this but the right way to handle this would be to use `locale.atoi `api, which is provided to do this exact task. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`str.replace` doesn't change the string *in loco*. You need to reassign it. Also, you shouldn't use `str` to name your variables.

```py
string = "3,443"
string = string.replace(",", "")
int_num = int(string)
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Using str.replace

You are not saving the variable after the `str.replace`. str.replace is not an in-place method and returns the string which has to be stored back to the variable.

More [details](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) here.

> Also, try not to use `str` as a variable name as it can cause issues with calling str methods

```
s = "3,443"
s = s.replace(",", "")
int_num = int(s)
int_num
```

```
3443
```

---

#### Using locale.atoi

The right way to do this however would be to use `locale`. More details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html).

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

s = "3,443"
locale.atoi(s)
```

```
3443
```

Answer (score 3):

You aren't replacing the original string. Also, I suggest against using `str` as a variable name, since `str()` is a function for converting an object to a string.

```
str = "3,443"
str = str.replace(",", "")
int_num = int(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.replace(",", "")` returns the replaced string and does not replace it in space. Strings are immutable.
You should assign the result.

Answer (score 2):

The function `replace` of strings returns a new string, leaving the original string untouched.
So all you need to do is assign the result of `replace` back to `str`.

Answer (score 1):

### Strings are immutable

In Python, [strings are immutable](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_string_immutability.htm). From that rule one can guess that, all methods called on a string will leave the original string unchanged. So this snippet:

```
s = "3,443"
s.replace(",", "")
```

will NOT change the value of `s`.

Instead of this it will return a new string. You need to handle that new string, eg with an assignement, if you want to do further things with it:

```
s = "3,443"
t = s.replace(",", "")
int(t)
```